# if the Seasonal Hybrid ESD (S-H-ESD) algorithm can be used even when seasonal does not exist

Tags: r, machine-learning, time-series, anomaly-detection, novelty-detection

First, I have monthly data from January 2000 to January 2020. However, seasonality does not appear. I wonder if S-H-ESD algorithms can be used even in this case.

Comment: What does "seasonality does not appear" mean? BTW, yes you can, even if only to  show a lack of seasonality.

Comment: @Carl thank you Carl ! As far as I know, the Seasonal Hybrid ESD (S-H-ESD) algorithm is known as the algorithm that extracts seasonal component from the original data and then uses them. But my data doesn't show a clear seasonal component , can I use it in this case?
I wonder why you can use it if you can. Thank you for your reply. [link](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1704.07706.pdf)

Comment: Well, Yuntae, https://github.com/twitter/AnomalyDetection, the repository of the original code developed by Twitter, doesn't say much. One would assume that the answer is yes, but, I would suggest creating synthetic data and testing that.

Comment: @Carl Thank you Carl !!!!! Have a nice day!!